# Sqoop2 giving error while installation

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, sqoop

I installed sqoop2 from Cloudera tarball.
I am able to install sqoop2 server and client.

After installation, `"http://localhost:12000"` address gives the result
containing a string "Apache Sqoop ROOT". I understand from this string
the server is running but when I request
`"http://localhost:12000/sqoop/version"` it gives:

HTTP Status 404

And in client shell when I do 
show version –all

I get this message

Exception has occurred during processing command
Exception: com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException Message: GET `http://172.20.104.226:12000/sqoop/version` returned a response status of 404 Not Found

sqoop.log

`2013-10-22 09:53:02,767 INFO  repository.JdbcRepositoryProvider [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryProvider.initialize(JdbcRepositoryProvider.java:67)] JdbcRepository initialized.
2013-10-22 09:53:02,767 INFO  repository.RepositoryManager [org.apache.sqoop.repository.RepositoryManager.initialize(RepositoryManager.java:118)] Creating or upgrading on disk structures if necessary
2013-10-22 09:53:03,543 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.begin(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:73)] Tx count-begin: 1, rollback: false
2013-10-22 09:53:03,543 INFO  repository.JdbcRepository 
2013-10-22 09:53:04,136 INFO  mapreduce.MapreduceSubmissionEngine [org.apache.sqoop.submission.mapreduce.MapreduceSubmissionEngine.initialize(MapreduceSubmissionEngine.java:100)] Found hadoop configuration file core-site.xml
2013-10-22 09:53:04,168 INFO  core.SqoopServer [org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.destroy(SqoopServer.java:35)] Shutting down Sqoop server`

**Catalina log**

```
`22 Oct, 2013 3:51:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/lib/sqoop/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:44 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 370 ms
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive sqoop.war
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/sqoop] startup failed due to previous errors
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver40] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] appears to have started a thread named [sqoop-config-file-poller] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@31a734ff]) and a value of type [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager] (value [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager@20d12eea]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@31a734ff]) and a value of type [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager] (value [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager@221f7708]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:46 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1762 ms
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:20 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:21 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/lib/sqoop/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:23 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 367 ms
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive sqoop.war
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/sqoop] startup failed due to previous errors
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver40] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] appears to have started a thread named [sqoop-config-file-poller] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@6bf51e5c]) and a value of type [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager] (value [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager@7e0b6ef8]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@6bf51e5c]) and a value of type [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager] (value [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager@259a8416]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:25 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2081 ms`

`22 Oct, 2013 3:51:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/lib/sqoop/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:44 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 370 ms
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive sqoop.war
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/sqoop] startup failed due to previous errors
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver40] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] appears to have started a thread named [sqoop-config-file-poller] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@31a734ff]) and a value of type [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager] (value [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager@20d12eea]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@31a734ff]) and a value of type [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager] (value [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager@221f7708]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:46 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1762 ms
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:20 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:21 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/lib/sqoop/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:23 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 367 ms
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive sqoop.war
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/sqoop] startup failed due to previous errors
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver40] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] appears to have started a thread named [sqoop-config-file-poller] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@6bf51e5c]) and a value of type [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager] (value [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager@7e0b6ef8]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@6bf51e5c]) and a value of type [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager] (value [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager@259a8416]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:25 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2081 ms`
```

**Localhost.log**

```
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient
    at org.apache.sqoop.submission.mapreduce.MapreduceSubmissionEngine.initialize(MapreduceSubmissionEngine.java:113)
    at org.apache.sqoop.framework.JobManager.initialize(JobManager.java:215)
    at org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.initialize(SqoopServer.java:53)
    at org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer.contextInitialized(ServerInitializer.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 28 more
22 Oct, 2013 3:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.sqoop.framework.JobManager.destroy(JobManager.java:176)
    at org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.destroy(SqoopServer.java:36)
    at org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer.contextDestroyed(ServerInitializer.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4245)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4886)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient
    at org.apache.sqoop.submission.mapreduce.MapreduceSubmissionEngine.initialize(MapreduceSubmissionEngine.java:113)
    at org.apache.sqoop.framework.JobManager.initialize(JobManager.java:215)
    at org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.initialize(SqoopServer.java:53)
    at org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer.contextInitialized(ServerInitializer.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 28 more
22 Oct, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.sqoop.framework.JobManager.destroy(JobManager.java:176)
    at org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.destroy(SqoopServer.java:36)
    at org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer.contextDestroyed(ServerInitializer.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4245)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4886)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Can anyone suggest me what went wrong

**New logs**

```
` org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Borrow prepareStatement from pool failed
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingConnection.prepareStatement(PoolingConnection.java:113)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313)
at org.apache.sqoop.repository.derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler.detectVersion(DerbyRepositoryHandler.java:293)
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema SQOOP does not exist
    PoolingConnection.java:285)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1179)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingConnection.prepareStatement(PoolingConnection.java:107)
... 35 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Schema 'SQOOP' does not exist
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 51 more
Caused by: ERROR 42Y07: Schema SQOOP does not exist
at org.apac `

Comment: Would you mind sharing with us the server logs?

Comment: hi this is my sqoop.log

Comment: Also please share the catalina log as some exceptions are available only there.

Comment: hi
shared catalina and localhost logs

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the root exception is this one:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient
```

It seems that Sqoop server is not able to find it's Hadoop dependencies. You've mentioned that you've installed the Sqoop via tarbals and not packages, so you will need to alter catalina.properties file. I would suggest to taking a look on the [default example file](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/sqoop2/dist/src/main/server/conf/catalina.properties#L48) and altering config file with proper locations of the Hadoop dependencies.

Comment: hi 
i added all the jars from hadoop now its giving me some different error

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make sure that inside `sqoop.properties`, the hadoop configuration directory `org.apache.sqoop.submission.engine.mapreduce.configuration.directory` should be set to the correct directory where hadoop configuration files exist. It is set to `/etc/hadoop/conf` by default but in my case, it is actually located under `/root/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop`

Answer (score 0):

please consider these points to track sqoop2 issue.

1. make sure your hadoop **namenode** cluster is running **keyless** (i.e without password).
2. make sure **NameNode, DataNode, NodeManager, ResourceManager, SecondaryNameNode & JobHistoryServer** is running on your system.
3. use edit your "**catalina.properties**" file with absolute paths for loading hadoop libraries because sometime relative path is not work properly.in my case.

   ```
   common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/../lib/*.jar,/home/infinity/HADOOP/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*.jar,/home/infinity/HADOOP/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*.jar,/home/infinity/HADOOP/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*.jar,/home/infinity/HADOOP/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*.jar,/home/infinity/HADOOP/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*.jar,/home/infinity/HADOOP/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*.jar,/home/infinity/HADOOP/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*.jar,/home/infinity/HADOOP/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*.jar,/home/infinity/HADOOP/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*.jar,/home/infinity/HADOOP/hive/lib/*.jar
   ```
4. use absolute path** on the place **@BASEDIR@**  and  **@LOGDIR@** in **sqoop.properties** file for easily tracking sqoop log files.
5. make sure hadoop instance directory location is available on your sqoop.properties file. In my case these are.

   ## Submission engine class

   ```
   org.apache.sqoop.submission.engine=org.apache.sqoop.submission.mapreduce.MapreduceSubmissionEngine
   ```

   ## Hadoop configuration directory

   ```
   org.apache.sqoop.submission.engine.mapreduce.configuration.directory=/home/infinity/HADOOP/hadoop/etc/hadoop
   ```

   ## Execution engine configuration

   ```
   org.apache.sqoop.execution.engine=org.apache.sqoop.execution.mapreduce.MapreduceExecutionEngine
   ```
6. if all setting is fine then start **sqoop2-server** using 
   **sqoop.sh server start**

Note:- 1. But, before run this command format your hadoop cluster namenode using this command **Hadoop namenode -format** then start your **sqoop2-server**.

if these all settings are perfectly fine in your system then it's not a configuration issue.
it's possibly a jar compatibility issue. because it occurs only when native jar file is missing or thirdparty jar file not supported by your current environment. i suggest you please make sure "catalina.properties" have all the basic native dependency jar file.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient
```

i hope this article will help what you wanna to track your problem.